# Does an auto-deleted question count toward a question ban?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban, automatic-deletion

I asked a question on SO that received many downvotes and was eventually closed. I edited the question to clarify my problem and to meet the guidelines. It began to be upvoted and many people voted to reopen it.

However, it was still negatively scored and closed when that nefarious 30-day mark, and it was permanently deleted by the Community ♦ user. I have been working tirelessly over the past few months providing good answers and improving questions (earning 250 rep in the meantime), but I can't seem to get out from under the ban.

I am wondering, does that question still affect my question ban? If it does, it has been permanently deleted, so there is no way that it can help me get out from under it.

Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007481/rendering-an-image-in-an-image-with-captions-in-gd

Comment: Details are secret, so no one really knows, but everything I have read strongly suggests that it will count no differently than a question deleted the community (i.e 10K users) or moderators.

Comment: If you see it in [deleted recent questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/2566339) you might try linking it here, or providing a screen shot of it so that people can help you with either improving the question or in the case of 10k users, casting undelete votes.

Comment: You're screwed. You just have to wait and hope your other questions can be made good enough to overcome mobs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I answered this before somewhere, but: the influence deleted questions have on your ability to continue asking questions is determined *primarily* by how they were received *before being deleted.*

In your case, the fact that the question was closed and heavily downvoted counts against you. The fact that it was deleted makes relatively little difference.

Your best bet to counteract this is to edit your *other* questions for clarity - in particular, focus on summarizing the specific problem you're solving in the title and/or introduction.