# Does undeleting questions help to unban an account?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, post-ban

I have recently been wondering if undeleting a deleted question in an account leads to the possible un-ban of question asking.

I know it states that if a user's positive contributions outweighs their negative ones, a question ban could be reversed. Since one of the factors leading to a question ban is deleted questions, does undeleting the questions counteract this?

Comment: I could only see this helping if the you deleted the question as soon as you got an answer. Undeleting it yourself might then help. Otherwise, deleted questions count no more than undeleted ones, it's just that deleting your poorly received questions doesn't prevent them from counting. Now, taking this a step further, undeleting _and improving_ your questions could potentially help you. You'll find [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/2607247) relevant. (It talks about if deleting questions can _cause_ a ban.)

Answer (score 15):

A deleted question *by itself* [doesn't factor into the ban calculation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/1079354), unless the deleted question had an answer, which is explicitly frowned upon.

Outside of that, it depends on what next steps you take with your question.  Merely surfacing a bad question will expose it to more criticism and potentially more downvotes, so you should look to undelete any questions that you have the ability to truly improve.

Comment: _"so you should look to undelete any questions that you have the ability to truly improve"_ - Just to clarify this for the OP, ideally you want to edit and improve them _before_ you undelete them, so they're not subject to more (potentially premature) downvotes.

Comment: _"A deleted question by itself doesn't factor into the ban calculation, unless the deleted question had an answer"_ Really? I was sure that having a bunch of downvoted questions was a bad start, but that deleting them all just made things worse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Deleting the downvoted questions does make it worse since one can't improve those questions easily; not without either being able to find one's own deleted posts or having a moderator link to them.  But the algorithm largely doesn't care about the fact that a question is deleted.

Comment: @Makoto: Can you provide a reference/source for that? I'm almost sure I read the opposite.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/1079354.  I'll add this reference to my answer, too.

Comment: [Shog seems to agree with you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280146/560648)

Comment: lol jinx :) Yep add that in for an upvote, cheers

Comment: @JamesThorpe per my recollection users with less than 10K can't edit their deleted questions

Comment: @gnat:  That wouldn't make much sense. I'm fairly confident that they can.

Comment: @Makoto I just tested that on [my deleted question at Math meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21680/hint-programmers-se-doesnt-do-coding-help-and-expect-research-before-asking) - edit link opens it but attempt to change anything raises a block message: "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed"

Comment: @gnat I agree with Makoto that that would be an odd restriction - would wonder the reasoning if that is the case

Comment: @JamesThorpe to prevent abusing edits to troll 10K users maybe. I guess intended way to improve deleted questions is - 1) prepare new revision offline, 2) flag to undelete, 3) edit new revision immediately after undeletion

Comment: @gnat Yeah that makes sense

Comment: So undeleted a question that has an answer will be beneficial towards getting rid of a question ban?