# What does undeleted question mean?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, undeleted-questions

And can someone explain where I can find deleted questions, so I can undelete (I guess it means reopen) them?

Comment: Your own questions, or 'any'? You do not have enough reputation - by a wide margin - to do that. (You are about [19,967 points short](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).)

Comment: I guess for any question I don't have enough reputation. How about my own questions?

Comment: You got any context for this question?

Comment: Seems relevant: [Does undeleting questions help to unban an account?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322437/does-undeleting-questions-help-to-unban-an-account)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An undeleted question is one which *was* deleted and now is not. This condition is usually caused by one or more voters voting to "undelete" the deleted post; the number of votes required is determined by the number of people who voted to delete, and the privilege level of the voter; see: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

You may view your own deleted questions, if they are less than 60 days old, by visiting the [deleted recent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile) page on your profile.